# event handling using c++/cli and using it in c#

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

-I want to raise an event whenever method showmessage is called.I want to catch it in C#
 code.

-I have written the event for it.

-Is it correct what i have done in Initialize function to associate the delegate with
  the function showmessage

-how to use this event in c#

```
C++/CLI

delegate void progressmsgdisplay(System::String ^ message);
progressmsgdisplay  ^ progressMsgNotify;
void Mclass::ShowMessage(System::String ^ message)
{ 
MessageBox(NULL, m_msg, m_box, NULL);
notify(message);
}
event progressmsgdisplay ^ notify 
{
    void add(progressmsgdisplay ^ d) 
    {
        progressMsgNotify += d;
    }


    void remove(progressmsgdisplay ^ d) 
    {
        progressMsgNotify -= d;
    }


    void raise(System::String ^ msg)
    {
       progressmsgdisplay ^ tmp = progressMsgNotify;
               if (tmp) 
        {
        tmp->Invoke(msg);
        }

    }
}

//void Mclass::Initialize(System::String ^ strProgressMsg)
//{
// progressMsgNotify=gcnew progressmsgdisplay(this,&Mclass::ShowMessage);
//}
```

-Mclass is the name of the class in which all of the above is declared and defined

```
C#
void display(string progressnotification)
 {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(progressnotification);
 }
void initialize()
{
 first = new Mclass();
 first.notify()+=display;
}
```

this did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just use EventHandler class in c++/cli and subscribe it in C#

```
//C++/CLI
public ref class SomeClass
{
    public:
    event EventHandler^ someEvent;
}

//C#
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass testclass = new SomeClass();
        testclass.someEvent += someEventHandler;
    }

    private void someEventHandler(Object obj, EventArgs args)
    {

    }
}
```

I haven't tried this yet. But I guess its worth a try.

Comment: error C2664: 'managed::Mclass::someEvent::raise' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'System::String ^ to 'System::EventArgs ^' 
                                    I am getting this error that since the default raise method requires System::EventArgs^ args as the second parameter and i need to pass System::string

Comment: I guess EventHandler<TEventArgs> Delegate would solve the problem. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx. Check the example given.